# Child's numberOfRowsInSection function doesn't be called?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I make a super class `ListViewController` which is a child of UITableViewController, and also make a class name `CoutryListViewController` which is a child of `ListViewController`, but in `CountryListViewController.m`, the numberOfRowsInSection function doesn't be called, can anyone help me?

In `ListViewController.m` implementation like:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

if ([tableView isEqual:self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView]) {
    // search
    return 1;
}
return self.indexTitles.count;
}
```

In `CountryListViewController.m` implementation like:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

if ([tableView isEqual:self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView]) {
    // search
    return self.searchResults.count;
}
NSLog(@"statesArray count: %ld", self.statesArray.count);
return self.statesArray.count;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I know what's wrong. Because the super class's `numberOfSectionsInTableView` function always return 0.